# Rails 4, highmaps, out of date JS files and problems with Mixed Content: xxxx was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, highcharts, cross-domain-policy

I have 2 questions regarding highcharts (using high maps also) and cross-domain policy issues. My site runs over https.

1. The Rails 4 installation of highcharts for rails seems to be out of date - the js files don't work when trying to implement maps. I had to add the links directly to my header - is this a recognised probelm?
2. This leads onto the second problem. The files aren't working on my production site because they are http (and not https). How does one circumvent this problem. I added "s" to the source url and this worked for some but not for

   ```
     $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=world-population-density.json&callback=?', function (geojson) {.....

   });
   ```

Which is necessary for my map. The line charts work fine. Its just the incoporation of maps which breaks.

Has anyone else had this problem and if so whats the fix?

Comment: Well for me https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=world-population-density.json&callback=? returns data, example: http://jsfiddle.net/r6ey8qdc/

Comment: Sebastian. I'm glad you answered as I have seen your other posts. May I ask - I'm supplying the function with my own data (JSON) served up by my controller (as a ruby variable). This all works fine in development and I know my data variable is correct. Does that mean I shouldn't even need the callback above - from what you've said and my reading of it, this call back is only supplying the data for the map. Is this correct? Or is it serving up the map itself also?

Comment: This is only data for value, not map (this is javascript file).